# Is there a way to describe attributes, using just graphs, links and nodes?

Tags: object, data-structures, attributes, language-agnostic, graph-theory

I've been thinking about this for a while but I can't seem to get my head around this.

(1) Say you have a simple graph with links and nodes. Some nodes are green and some nodes are red.

(2) It seems to me that we could represent this by adding two special 'color' nodes, and linking them to the nodes that have that color.

(3) However, 'being a color node', is in itself an attribute. So we could represent this, again, by adding a special node that represents this, and linking the color nodes to that one. This could go on ad infinitum.

[see this image for illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWAAe.jpg)
Is there a way to do describe attributes, using *only* nodes and links? I.e. is there a way to break out of the infinite regression without using 'special' nodes?

Comment: Yes, you can define the struct or class for nodes, something like this,


`struct Node{
      string color_attribute;
      Node[] children;


}`

Answer (score 0):

### In various data structures (linked lists, trees, graphs etc.) nodes always contain some data.

This is also necessary in **recursive data structures** like a **linked list** or a **tree**, were the nodes of such data structures include themselves in data. This is because a list can be a list of a list and a tree can be a tree of a tree of a tree etc.

In a graph you could kind of get a **pass** for nodes, because for instance you can define and represent a graph with a matrix with number nodes. However, if you want it to be for colours, you would need a dictionary (or an associative arrays) to map your values with other values.

This graph can be represented by a matrix like this:

[image: from grevian.org]

```
   5|Y x x x Y             Dictionary // a, b, c, d, e could be colours or other atomic values mapped.
   4|x x Y Y x             a -> 1
   3|Y x Y Y Y             b -> 2
   2|Y Y x x x             c -> 3
   1|Y Y Y x Y             d -> 4
     - - - - -             e -> 5
     1 2 3 4 5

x -> represents there's no link (edge) between the nodes.
Y -> represents there's a link (edge) between the nodes.
```